# Is this overkill for setting defining SESSION

Tags: php

I have the below code running on at the top of every file. Do I need the if statement. I have been using this implementation for a long time and most likely acquired it when I was first learning. 
My understanding now is that I do not require the if statement but I would like some clarification if this is a good practice or not.

```
<?php
// Inialize session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the `if` is indeed not required. However, I'd say it's good practice to keep the `if` regardless.
`isset` is, after all, a language construct, whereas `session_start` is a function call. Function calls are slower than language constructs, no matter how you look at it.

By adding the `if (isset($_SESSION))` checks, you avoid calling functions like `session_start`, or as others have suggested `session_id` or `session_status` too many times.
Just look at the statements, and count the function calls:

```
if (isset($_SESSION))
//if, language construct
//isset, language construct
//$_SESSION, lookup of super-global
//----------------------------------
//Total function calls: 0
```

Compared to:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
//if, language construct
//session_status(), function call
//PHP_SESSION_NONE, lookup of global, predefined constant
//----------------------------------------------------------
//total function calls: 1
```

And, of course:

```
if(session_id() == '') 
//if, lang construct
//session_id(), function call
//'' string consant
//-------------------------------
// 1 function call
```

In all 3 cases, if when the `if` evaluates to true, a `session_start` function call ensues. What you have now will result in 1 function call *once*, the alternatives will result in *two* function calls once, and then call 1 function each time.

Personally, I'd urge you to to look into ways of avoiding the *need* of all those `session_start` calls. Any decent framework, through `.htaccess` rewrite rules, manage to direct all requests through a single point of entry (most of the times, this is a `index.php` file). There, you can call `session_start`. The other scripts, then, don't have to bother with code like that.

Comment: My understanding is that session_start needs to be called on every page. But I know in my small applications I will not call session_start twice so it would be safe to remove the if statement?

Comment: @Max: Yes, removing the `if` is safe. Regardless of the session being started or not. However: the overhead of that `if` is so small, I wouldn't bother. You never know that, as your project grows, that `if` will need to be added again. I'd say: leave your code as-is, it's better to be safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these methods instead of your code.It is a good practice to check the session is set or not.It will help to prevent an unwanted function call.**One checking is better than one unwanted function call.**,So you can reduce execution time.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
      session_start();
   }
```

Or

```
 if(session_id() == '') {
  session_start();
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a better implementation?

Comment: Why is this better or recommended over simply running session_start in every file no matter what

Comment: @Max: It isn't: `session_status` or `session_id` are both function calls, `isset` is a language construct, and thus it is faster. the [docs](http://www.php.net/session_status) state this quite clearly. using `isset` + `session_start` means you'll only call `session_start` when required, and avoid too many function calls

Comment: Weird. You've edited, and now say that a check is better than an unwanted/pointless function call. I agree, but your checks still require a function call. What the OP has ATM is, therefore, better than the alternatives you suggest

Answer (score -1):

Your if-statement is unnecessary.

To check if session is started:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
 //not started
      session_start();
}
 else {
      // session has been started
 }
```

Comment: The `$_SESSION` variable is not always set.